# Multiple Conditions in Ternary Operator

Tags: php, operators

I want to check if a variable is equal to b or c using tertiary operator. is it possible to do that?

```
 $value = ($variable == 'b' or 'c')? true: false;
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: @hek2mgl i was getting an error :P

Comment: Users with less than 500 reputation would have gotten a downvote for this question you get an upvote mhhh...

Comment: @Layne, yeah it is at least a questionable post compared to others which look nearly the same..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, separate your conditions using `||` operator, like so:

```
$value = ($variable == 'a' || $variable == 'b') ? true : false;
```

However, for *this* particular case, a ternary operator isn't necessary! You can directly use the return value:

```
$value = ($variable == 'a' || $variable == 'b');
```

Answer (score 3):

No need Ternary Operator!

Try the following

```
$value = ($variable == 'a' || $variable == 'b');
```

Comment: +1 - Good point. I've added it as an alternative option in my answer. :)

Comment: @AmalMurali I've seen that.. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
$value = ($variable == 'a' || $variable == 'b')? true: false;
```